# Marketing cloud mobilePush batch Id

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

Our use case requires sending an API request from within the push notification message (SSJS/AMPSCript).

We have an issue when a contact has several device IDs registered, which can happen every time a user deletes and reinstalls the app, or just replaces it with a new device.

During journey send, multiple attempts will be made to send push messages to all opted-in registered devices, potentially causing the API call to execute redundantly.

To address this issue, we aim to block these duplicate API calls in the remote server by including a batch ID (if such exists) in the API payload.
Or any other identifier of the specific push.

Any suggestions for extracting this ID from the message or other ideas are welcome.